# Make decimal (not integer) Steps in MultiHandleSliderExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the `MultiHandleSliderExtender` and I want the values to move between 0.01-1.00.

I tried using minimum=0, maximum=1 steps=100 and decimals=2 and it didn't work.  It simply jumps from 0 to 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try rebuilding you Page and Solution might be due to script caching. Try the below code it works for me.

```
<asp:SliderExtender runat="server" id="slider" behaviorid="slider" boundcontrolid="txtSlider"
decimals="2"
minimum="0"
maximum="1"
steps="100"
length="200"
enablehandleanimation="true"
orientation="Horizontal"
tooltiptext="current value is {0}"
targetcontrolid="txtSlider">
</asp:SliderExtender>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSlider"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its need to change `MultiHandleSliderTargets` property `DecimalPlaces=2` as well

**DecimalPlaces** - The number of decimal places to format the bound control's value.

```
 <MultiHandleSliderTargets>
        <ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" Decimals="2" />
        <ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" Decimals="2" />
 </MultiHandleSliderTargets>
```

for more details see [Here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MultiHandleSlider/MultiHandleSlider.aspx)